# Arithmetic in sql query

Tags: sql

I've got a dynamic number of rows I'm pulling that I want to do some math on. Here's the story:

**Table Columns:**

- id
- timestamp
- user_id
- coupon_id
- use_count

**Current Query:**

```
"SELECT cu.id, cu.use_count 
FROM coupons_used cu
WHERE cu.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']->ID . ";";
```

**The Rules:**

the `use_count` input can only ever be `1` or `-1`.

**Desired Result:**

I know I'll pull in rows that have the same `coupon_id` so what I'm hoping to do is accomplish all the adding / subtracting with mysql so I'll have one row for each unique `coupon_id` with a grand total for each row's `use_count`. I'm doing this 1) to save a step and 2) to learn something I don't know yet.

**Current Output:**

```
id:1, timestamp:5/6/15, user_id:1, coupon_id:1, use_count:1
id:2, timestamp:5/7/15, user_id:1, coupon_id:1, use_count:-1
id:3, timestamp:5/7/15, user_id:1, coupon_id:1, use_count:1
id:4, timestamp:5/8/15, user_id:1, coupon_id:1, use_count:1
```

**Desired Output**

`id:null, timestamp:null, user_id:1, coupon_id:1, use_count:2 // 1 + -1 + 1`

Comment: I still don't know what you are trying to do...

Comment: Are you just looking for `sum`?

Comment: Sounds like basic `sum` with `group by`. Is this a trick question?

Comment: You've failed to clearly describe the problem you're having or ask a question that can be answered. Do you need to Google for a SQL tutorial to learn about aggregate functions such as SUM()?

Comment: I added a little more code for current output and desired output. I'm not an SQL guy so if this is basic stuff I apologize.

Comment: You violate your rules by the `Desired Output` section's `use_count` column having the value of 2.

Comment: The problem is not the basic level of the question, although it is an RTFM question. The problem is this shows a lack of research efforts on your part. Not something I would expect from someone with your reputation. btw, I'm not the one that downvoted.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I can appreciate that. My rep comes from programming, not SQL. I was hoping a simple question would have a simple answer so the irony to me is that as simple as this question is, no one in the comments answered it. Is SOF only a place for elitists now?

Comment: The way I look at it is this: Nobody knows everything. It's ok to ask RTFM questions, but only if you really have done the RTFM first :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an "aggregate function".  In this case, you want to use the `SUM` aggregate function in conjunction with a `Group By` clause.  This will return a single record for each unique result specified in the Group By:

```
"SELECT cu.id, SUM(cu.use_count) 
FROM coupons_used cu
WHERE cu.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']->ID . "
GROUP BY cu.coupon_id;";
```